# How do you create a template definition for a fixed-size array class in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, templates

I need to create a template because I don't know what it's an array of.  And it needs to be of the size that's passed in the constructor.  So here is what I got and I got all sorts of errors.  I am a beginner to C++ so any help is appreciated :)

```
template <typename T, int N>
class Array
{
  public:
    T& operator[](int index)
    {
      return data[index];
    }
  private:
    int size;
    T *data[N];
};
```

I think you understand what I'm trying to do.  I also need to overload the subscript operator, as you can see.  Not sure if I need a reference or a pointer or what.  I did have a constructor but it wasn't working properly.

Comment: `T *data[N];` should be `T data[N];`

Comment: use `std::array`, that's a fixed size array class for you.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf This should be an answer.

Comment: "So here is what I got and I got all sorts of errors." - what errors - list them.  Anyway, your operator's ok, you probably should use `size_t` instead of `int` and add `const T& operator[](size_t index) const { return data[index]; }`, perhaps `size_t size() const { return N; }`... other things depend on your needs.

Comment: @Eric: See how we fix indentation for the next time: (no `<br>`, just select code and *ctrl + K*)

Comment: In fact it seems it should be `std::vector` as *"size that's passed in the constructor"*

Comment: I believe this is going to end up being an assignment.

Comment: Just create a wrapper around `std::vector` that has no size-changing functions.

Comment: Here's the reference for [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Comment: You can look at how your standard library implements `std::array`. It's usually quite straightforward, except they need to accommodate zero-length arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a corrected version with a sample main as well:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <typename T, int N>
class Array
{
  public:
    T& operator[](int index)
    {
      // add check for array index out of bounds i.e. access within 0 to N-1
      return data[index];
    }
    Array() {
        data = new T[size = N];
    }
    ~Array() {
        if (data)
            delete [] data;
    }
  private:
    int size;
    T *data;
};

int main(void) {
    Array<int, 4> a;
    a[0] = 5;
    cout << a[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much.  I understand the concepts well.  I just have a hard time in the C++ language.  The syntax gets me.  Your example makes the implementation in C++ much more clear to me.

Comment: The whole point of passing the size as a template parameter is to avoid using dynamic allocation.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see your template is containing an array of *pointers*, which from what I read and from your [] operator implementation is not what you intend to do. So first you should remove the *** from :

```
T *data[N];
```

You should probably initialize the size of your template from your constructor, thus you should change :

```
T *data[N];
```

to :

```
T* data;
```

and :

```
template <typename T, int N>
```

to :

```
template<typename T>
```

Now that changes the implementation a bit, you should now write a constructor like that :

```
template<typename T>
Array(int n) {
    data = new T[n];
}
```

and now you should also add a destructor like that :

```
~Array() {
    delete[] data;
}
```

and there you go :)

However if you want to keep the size as an argument of the template your constructor go like :

```
template<typename T, int N>
Array() {
}
```

and the declaration of data :

```
T data[N];
```

As said in comments, you may want to use std::array in "real life" conditions, but as a training, implementing your own Array is a good thing to do, that's a training most computer schools do after all.

Comment: Templates can have non-type parameters.

Comment: And what issues exactly ? I do want to enhance my answer if it has issues but if you don't say what they are how could I ? Plus this is one of the most standard ways to do Arrays. I answered while keeping in mind his choices (array with a pointer and int as template argument) and I adviced him to do differently to fit the C++ standard way of doing.

If he wants to make his own implementations of arrays to train, he should. Implementing basic versions of standard or STL containers is a good training ;)

Comment: @DevilBlackDeath First of all one should not use `new` `delete` directly in c++, second the sample doesn't implement the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) properly. Also I don't see a point to create the `T` array with `new` if the size is fixed using the template parameter `N`.

Comment: True about your last point. However the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) is of the author's responsibility, he asked about why it didn't work and how to make it work. And why exactly should new and delete be avoided? (`malloc` and `free` should be avoided however) I implemented smart pointers in C++03 and I don't really see how I could have done without `new` `delete`

Comment: @DevilBlackDeath If `T data[N];` is used the sentence _'However the destructor are still the same as my initial solution !'_ is certainly wrong. `delete[]` isn't needed in this case.

Comment: Thanks, did so many edits at once that I lost track of what I said ;) Shouldn't the poster accept Debasish's answer? :S